# SQL - Select and return functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using SQL*Plus. This is what I am to do:  Using the BOOK_ORDER table, create a query using the correct function to return the order number, the date ordered, the date shipped, and a column representing the number of months between the two dates for all columns where a date shipped exists. Format the number returned from the function to display only two decimals, and give the column an alias of "Months Between".

NOTE: Be sure that all of the numbers in the fourth column are positive numbers

I've started it this way; however, I am a bit lost and confused in what I am doing.

```
SELECT BOOK_ORDER.ORDERID, BOOK_ORDER.ORDERDATE, BOOK_ORDER.SHIPDATE ||', ' ||
```

Can someone help?

Comment: provide table structure including all foreign and primary key constraints, sample data, desired output and an actual sql query of what you've tried. (The code you gave is just part of a query)

Comment: Book_Customer Table
PK- Customer Req
LastName Req
FirstName Req
Addresss Req
City Req
State Req
Zip Req

Book_order Table
PK- OrderID Req
Fk1 - CustomerID Req
OrderDate Req
shipDate not required
ShipStreet Req
ShipCity req
ShipState req
ShipZip Req

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment clearly points to using the Oracle built-in function MONTHS_BETWEEN.  It's in the documentation.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm).

```
select b.orderid
       , b.orderdate
       , b.shipdate 
       , round(months_between(b.orderdate, b.shipdate),2) as "months between"
from book_order b
where b.shipdate is not null
/
```

Please be sure to give SO credit when you hand in your homemwork.